# MDX Scope Assignment returns same value

Tags: scope, mdx

I have some MDX in my SSAS cube something like:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[xx] AS 1;

SCOPE ([Measures].[xx]);

   SCOPE ([Measures].[xx], [DimA].[DimA Hierarchy].Members);
       This= 20;
   END SCOPE;

   SCOPE ([Measures].[xx], [DimB].[DimB Hierarchy].Members);
       This= 2;
   END SCOPE;

END SCOPE;
```

Browsing the cube and selecting the [xx] measure *always* returns 2, no matter if I use the DimA, DimB or no dimensions at all.

If I swap the order of the inner scope declrations, (ie DimB's scope before DimA's) I get 20 no matter what.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SCOPE` only makes sense if you use it on a subset of the members of a hierarchy.

`[DimB].[DimB Hierarchy].Members` and `[DimA].[DimA Hierarchy].Members` have no effect in scope, as they refer to **all** members of the hierarchy. Hence, one of these is always the current member, and the last scope always is used. Except you define a calculated member on that hierarchy, and it is the current member.

You probably want at least to exclude the `All` member, so that the `SCOPE` is only used for other members that this member, which is by default the current member if you do not use the hierarchy at all. In case `DimA Hierarchy` is an attribute hierarchy and not a user hierarchy, you can use `[DimA].[DimA Hierarchy].[DimA Hierarchy].Members` to  get the members of the `DimA Hierarchy` level, which are all members except the `All` member.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[xx] AS 1;

SCOPE ([Measures].[xx]);

   SCOPE ([DimA].[DimA Hierarchy].Members);
       This= 20;
   END SCOPE;

   SCOPE ([DimB].[DimB Hierarchy].Members);
       This= 2;
   END SCOPE;

END SCOPE;
```